# Disable suexec or disallow users from writing to the document root

Tags: centos

Hello panel I am new here I found the community on google here is my problem we deployed nessus tenable to do the vulnerability scans so on a centos environment we have the following vulnerabilities:

Apache mod_suexec Multiple Privilege Escalation Vulnerabilities

it is recommended to
Disable suexec or disallow users from writing to the document root

can you help me I am new to Linux environments
Image description

[vulnerability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVD7C.png)

i want to resevolve vulnerability in centos